# Memory ordering and RMW instruction definitions

Tags: consistency-model

The typical definition of an RMW instruction with e.g. sequential consistency is an instruction where no memory operation can happen between the load and the store in the global memory order.

Is there a reason to use this definition? Why is it not sufficient to just require that no operation to the same memory address can happen between the load and the store? Are these definitions equivalent? What about if you relax the memory model to something like x86 TSO?